# pygame event.key == pygame.K_d and l == 1 or 0

Tags: python, pygame

So I am making a program were you have to rapidly spam A and D on your keyboard to advance. This is my running system:

```
if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
    if (event.key == pygame.K_a) and (i is 2 or 0):
        y_change = display_height/200
        i = 1
    elif (event.key == pygame.K_d) and (i is 1 or 0):
        y_change = display_height/200
        i = 2
```

This is supposed to make it so that you can't press A or D twice and get a result. But instead of that it does completely nothing.

EDIT: Using deepspace's solution I solved (Switch i is 2 or 0 to i in [2, 0](same for i is 1 or 0)) the problem

Comment: Do you define `i` elsewhere?

Comment: Not sure if that is the root cause of your issue, but another problem is that `i is 2 or 0` and `i is 1 or 0` don't behave as you think. For example, if `i == 0`, `i is 1 or 0` will evaluate to `0` and then to `False` instead of the `True` that you expect. You should change these to `i in [0, 2]` and `i in [0, 1]` respectively.

Comment: @DeepSpace Yup, It worked that way. thx

Answer (score 0):

I think you're alternating A and D, right?  How about this?

```
expected_key = pygame.K_a   # somewhere in your initialization code

... other code ...

if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
    if (event.key == pygame.K_a) and (event.key == expected_key):
        y_change = display_height/200
        expected_key = pygame.K_d
    elif (event.key == pygame.K_d) and (event.key == expected_key):
        y_change = display_height/200
        expected_key = pygame.K_a
```

Or, for multiple keys,

```
expected_keys = [pygame.K_a, pygame.K_d]   # somewhere in your initialization code
next_keys = {pygame.K_a: [pygame.K_d], pygame.K_d: [pygame.K_a]}
    # after an A, you want a D, and vice versa

... other code ...

if (event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN) and (event.key in expected_keys):
    y_change = display_height/200
    expected_keys = next_keys[event.key]
```

`expected_keys` is the one or more keys you're willing to process now, and `next_keys` tells you what you'll accept after a particular key was pressed.